# Viewcontroller background image with horizontal animation

Tags: ios, swift, animation

I'm trying to create an animated background image for one of my view controllers where the image scrolls horizontally from left to right and then repeats when it has reached the end of the image horizontally. This effect is extremely common in games with SpriteKit but there isn't clear information anywhere on how to do it in a standard view controller with UIKit. Extra points if you can tell me how to set the image's top bounds to the bottom of the navigation bar rather than the top of the view controller :)

Here is the image:
[image: backgroundimage]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use two copies of the image. Start with one image fully occupying the screen. The other is to its left. Animate to the right, so that the second copy pushes the first copy off the screen. When the animation reaches the end, so that just one copy is fully occupying the screen, jump back to the start and repeat. The jump will not be visible because the images are identical and the jump is performed when they are in identical positions.

The nice thing is that the behavior I just described is the default for a repeating CABasicAnimation; it jumps back to the start automatically at the end of every repetition. Thus I was able to write a proof-of-concept very quickly (Swift 3, iOS 10):

```
    let im = UIImage(named:"stuff")!
    // create double image
    let r = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size:
        CGSize(width:im.size.width*2,height:im.size.height))
    let im2 = r.image { _ in
        im.draw(at: .zero)
        im.draw(at: CGPoint(x: im.size.width, y: 0))
    }
    // create layer to hold double image
    let imlay = CALayer()
    imlay.frame.size = im2.size
    imlay.contents = im2.cgImage
    // put it inside a single-image-sized container
    let scroll = CALayer()
    scroll.frame = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: im.size)
    scroll.masksToBounds = true
    scroll.addSublayer(imlay)
    scroll.bounds.origin = CGPoint(x:im.size.width, y:0)
    // put it in the interface
    self.view.layer.addSublayer(scroll)
    // animate
    let anim = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "bounds.origin")
    anim.toValue = NSValue(cgPoint: .zero)
    anim.duration = 10
    anim.repeatCount = .infinity
    scroll.add(anim, forKey: nil)
```

Comment: I've put up a YouTube video to show the result: https://youtu.be/wRf3plbSd1g My test image was just a portion of your image, but that makes no difference. As you can see, the effect is of continuous scrolling to the right.

Comment: Matt this is awesome. Thank you so much for doing this, it worked perfectly.

Comment: I knew you'd like it. Delighted to help; putting this example together was so much more fun than what I was _supposed_ to be doing!

Comment: Oh, one more thing: my choice of layers rather than views is not the only way to do this. You might prefer to use views because if you rotate the device the layers do not get automatically resized when the app rotates.

Comment: That's an easy switch. Thanks so much for going above and beyond for this, it's a cool effect.

Comment: @matt 2021 and still saving lives!

Answer (score 1):

```
You can achieve it by setting the `frame` of your `imageview` within an animation block like below:


func animate(){
        imageView.frame.origin.x = 0
        UIView.animateWithDuration(2, delay: 0.0, options: .CurveLinear, animations: {[unowned self] () -> Void in

            self.imageView.frame.origin.x = self.view.frame.size.width
            }) {[unowned self] (finsihed) -> Void in
                self.animate()
        }

    }
```